# IDE0059 Unnecessary assignment of a value to 'result'

Tags: c#, blazor, compiler-warnings

```
protected async Task HandleValidSubmit()
{
     Mapper.Map(EditEmployeeModel, Employee);

     Employee result = null;

     if (Employee.EmployeeId != 0)
     {
         result = await EmployeeService.UpdateEmployee(Employee);
     }
     else
     {
         result = await EmployeeService.CreateEmployee(Employee);
     }
     if (result != null)
     {
         NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
     }
  }
```

---

I get a message: IDE0059 Unnecessary assignment of a value to 'result'

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Simple as: `Employee result;`. You always assign something to `result`

Answer (score 2):

Both branches of the `if` and the `else` assign a value to `result`, so you don't need to initialize it with `null`. This `null` is never read and will just be overwritten anyway.

Comment: ... and unnecesary assignments can hide errors when you for instance later change that if/else.